# How to draw a dotted rectangle around part of equation?

Tags: equations, boxes, framed

I need to produce a following image:

[image: equation]

I found a `\boxdot` symbol in ams package but can not find any dotted box.

Comment: \boxdot (from amssymb) is a box with a dot inside.  The easiest way to create a dotted box of a given size is to use TikZ (or possibly graphicx if you have an image).

Comment: So _that's_ how Microsoft Word makes those boxes in the equation editor!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [**dashbox package**](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/dashbox) can be tweaked to do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{dashbox}
\newcommand\emptydottedbox{%
    \setlength{\dashlength}{1pt}%     % length of dash + gap
    \setlength{\dashdash}{0.5pt}%     % length of dash
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%     % width of line
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}%        % separation between box and inner content
    \dbox{\ensuremath{\phantom{x}}}%
    }

\begin{document}

\[
\int_{\emptydottedbox}^{\emptydottedbox} \emptydottedbox
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want some more `%`, try `a\emptydottedbox b` outside math mode.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. you're right, thanks. Though it probably won't be used outsite math mode.

Answer (score 7):

With tikz you can draw these boxes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\smallbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,dotted] (0,0) rectangle
(0.3, 0.3);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\newcommand{\medbox}{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,dotted] (0,0) rectangle
(0.5, 0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

\[\int_{\smallbox}^{\smallbox} {\medbox} \]
\end{document}
```

Maybe you need to fiddle a bit with the dimensions and/or the spacing.

[image]

Comment: You could generalize it, with e.g. `\newcommand\DotBox[1][0.3]{\tikz\draw[thick,dotted] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);}`. (And by the way, you also have a spurious space, add a `%` right after `\end{tikzpicture}`, or move the closing brace up.)